# why doesn't a dot appear in the second code for Feynman diagram produced by feynmf?

Tags: feynmf

I tried this code :

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{a1}
    \fmfright{y1}
    \fmf{photon}{a1,j1,y1}
   \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

~

\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{i1}
    \fmfright{o1}
    \fmf{photon}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmfdot{v1}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=4}{v1}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

However, the second code does not produce the desired dot in the middle of the wavy line...and I cannot figure out why....It is so extremely frustrating. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Completely unrelated: Instead of `blank line ~ blank line`, it would be better to use `\bigskip`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a full MWE your 2nd code work perfectly...There is the dot in the middle of the photon. Also the first work.

[image]

**Second example:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfleft{i1}
\fmfright{o1}
\fmf{photon}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmfdot{v1}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=4}{v1}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

**First example:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{a1}
    \fmfright{y1}
    \fmf{photon}{a1,j1,y1}
   \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]